# error CS0006 metadata file; fileuploadcontrol.dll'could not be found

Tags: c#

how can I be able to solve this

> error Severity Code   Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0006  Metadata file
>   'C:\Users\User\source\repos\ONLINEMOVIETICKETBOOKINGPROJECTMONICAH\FileUploadControl\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\FileUploadControl.dll'
>   could not be
>   found ONLINEMOVIETICKETBOOKINGPROJECT C:\Users\User\source\repos\ONLINEMOVIETICKETBOOKINGPROJECTMONICAH\ONLINEMOVIETICKETBOOKINGPROJECT\CSC   1   N/A

Comment: First step is to clearly describe the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Project is expecting the library "FileUploadControl.dll" at the following location, ensure it's there:

> C:\Users\User\source\repos\ONLINEMOVIETICKETBOOKINGPROJECTMONICAH\FileUploadControl\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0

If it is available on the location, check the .net framework version.